# Singleton Lock for Azure Webjob's TimerTrigger accross multiple regions

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a timer-triggered WebJob deployed across multiple regions and it is getting triggering concurrently from all regions on given scheduled time, how do I make sure that only one instance of the job runs at a time?
I tried applying `Singleton` attribute and `"is_singleton": true` but still  it is triggering from all regions.

Is there any other way to achieve this? This [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/735) says that Singleton attribute no longer works for this purpose and also I don't see any lock file created in the azure blob storage. If it's true how do we implement this to ensure only one region is triggered from multiple regions? Or if there is any other inbuilt way of achieving this with WebJob SDK that would be really helpful to me.

`Program.cs`:

```
var builder = new HostBuilder();
builder
    .ConfigureWebJobs((context, b) =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
    });
var host = builder.Build();
using (host)
{
    var jobHost = host.Services.GetService(typeof(IJobHost)) as JobHost;
    await host.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await jobHost.CallAsync("Run").ConfigureAwait(false);
    await host.StopAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

`Function.cs`:

```
[Singleton]
[NoAutomaticTrigger]
public async Task Run()
{
}
```

`settings.job`:

```
{
  "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *",
  "is_singleton": true
}
```

NuGet package:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="4.0.1" />
```

Comment: Heres a library for doing your own cron also, inside the function: https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you want each region to run, but just not at the same time.

One simple solution would be to stagger them so they don't all run at the same time but you give each one a slightly different cron time, such as 10m apart from each other.

But supposing you couldn't predict how long they will run or you essentially want them to run much faster then the minimum 10m apart, and supposing they could all access a database, such a Azure Cosmos Mongo, then you could add a table and some simple logic which would essentially model a "locking" pattern.

In mongodb you can use the [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) function to do an atomic update on a well known document which will allow only one process to "lock" a document at a time.

The database in this case contains a collection (aka table) with a single document (aka row) that looks like this:

```
interface ILock {
  state: 'UNLOCKED' | 'LOCKED';
  lockedBy: null | string;
  lockedAt: null | Date;
}
```

##### psuedo code

```
while (true)
{
  // todo: add some kind of timeout here so it doesn't run forever.

  // `findOneAndUpdate` is atomic, if multiple processes
  // attempt to do this modification simultaneously
  // only one will succeed, the others will get an `undefined`
  // result to indicate the document was not found.
  var lock = await this.db.locks.findOneAndUpdate(
    { state: 'UNLOCKED' },
    {
      $set: {
        state: 'LOCKED',
        lockedBy: this.jobId,
        lockedAt: new Date()
      }
    }
  )

  if (lock) {
    try {
      // you have the lock, do your thing...
      await DoWork();
      // you are done, exit the loop.
      return;
    } finally {
      // don't forget to unlock!
      await this.db.locks.findOneAndUpdate(
        { state: 'LOCKED' },
        {
          $set: {
            state: 'UNLOCKED',
          }
        }
      )
    }
  } else {
    // you are not the one neo, take the blue pill...
    await sleep(3000)
  }
  
}
```

Comment: This will altogether restrict to one region and there is no point in deploying to multiple regions. The webjob has to be in multiple regions and it has to run in any one of the region . For example east us@1am, west us@2 am, west us @3am, east us@4am..  And I'm more looking for way of default sdk implementation if there are any.

Comment: Ok so you want them all to run... just not at the same time? So they'd all try one would go then the others would wait, etc. until they all run once?

Comment: If that's the case you could stagger their schedules so each one has a different schedule. Or you could use a database, I'll update my answer with an example of that.

Comment: In response to your above schedules comments.. That would mean to generate settings.job at release time for each region release or somehow tell azure webjob to use different setting.job for different regions (don't know how to achieve this).

Comment: I believe cosmos will allow you to do multi-region atomic operations, believe it or not. Double check me on that but I'm pretty sure that is one of its stronger points in favor. Also the serverless mode is very nice, cost wise, for things like this which may have very low utilization throughout the day.

Comment: In response to your updated answer for lock mechanism. `[Singleton]` attribute was supposed do the same (using azure blob storage lease). It should create lease and not allow other regions to run until the lease is locked. If I don't find any inbuild sdk way to do this then will try to follow your lock mechanism but instead with storage blob lease

Comment: Sure, so long as all regions can access it and the lock is atomic you should be able to accomplish it.